# Research request: faculty absences vs. student evaluations

Tags: teaching, course-evaluation

I am looking for **rigorous**, **empirical**, and preferably but not necessarily **peer-reviewed** research on the relationship between **faculty absences** and **student evaluations of teaching**.

Background: Teachers occasionally have to be absent from their classes. This is sometimes for work-related reasons (e.g., travel to a conference) and sometimes for personal reasons (e.g., illness or family emergency). Usually this entails finding a substitute or canceling a class.

I am interested in any statistical information on questions like the following:

- Does the number of faculty absences correlate clearly with numerical student evaluations?
- Are faculty absences particularly noted on narrative student evaluations?

I am particularly interested in these questions at the **university level**, but would be happy to hear information about other levels. Of course, I do not know if such research has been done, and perhaps it has not. In that case, pointers to similar research would be helpful.

I am **not** particularly interested in anecdotes ("One semester I was absent twelve times and my evaluations were great!") or in data-free theorizing ("Of course there will be/won't be a correlation...").

Comment: I doubt it has been done. I'll bet that the variation far outweighs any conclusions that can be applied. What is the point of it? And I suggest that you don't take it on as a research topic.

Comment: Who cares? More precisely, what could be the possible takeaways of such research? If students hate it, will faculty make sure to get sick less often, or go to fewer conferences?

Comment: @KevinArlin Well, one could adjust the scores of faculty based on their absence so the one semester they got pneumonia doesn't reflect poorly on them.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Mmm, I suppose. Doesn't sound like anywhere close to a common enough or predictable enough problem to use any resources on to me.

Comment: @KevinArlin I agree generally